# Why some validator have 2x32eth deposit?

Tags: eth-2.0, staking, validators

I see some validators on beaconcha.in, for instance 0xae0a59afa484054a4960ee3699d7e518d9273ff65bab932d3217f69770a48ddfbe646d970a422c88adcff8117ce30f47 that have 2x 32eth deposit. The max active stake by validator is 32. Why some did 2 deposits? it's a validator funded at genesis. Is it just a user mistake depositing twice or something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is likely a user mistake (due to a technical error or misunderstanding the instructions) as you only get rewards on the first 32 ETH of the validator. The extra ethers are stucked until withdrawal functionality is added to the protocol.

Regarding the [validator](https://beaconcha.in/validator/20082) that you provided as an example we can see the [associated address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbc31c592076a72a5f07cf11a28dffb396cac5fa2) did a total of 3 deposits :

- [first 32ETH deposit](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8900cf199583ca108a55a1384073488e29007cb03c49e7a80e483687e60e747e) on November 2020 on the validator mentioned above ;
- [second 32ETH deposit](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x14bcd22c8611e6f36346ecd5b69daabd5740b0e7e1b08bfa9f80f9045e7f149d) on December 2020 on the same validator --> mistake ;
- [third 32ETH deposit](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbb8d6628737927f97cb7c73dc100c4500c99a6ab21b402d1feec967c7c6edd20) a few hours later on a [new validator](https://beaconcha.in/validator/aa4f1bed7ec37a5efb4f369f99a7f2a4d6f1f54fbfbd125d9f4cf3c9384cbcac77d270be6c2264106a81697040bf8f83) --> action to mitigate the mistake.